# Am able to do dial-up connection to the Internet on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, pppoe, dsl-modem

I have a modem with a PON port(fibre) and a RJ45 port. On Windows I am able to do a dial-up connection to the Internet without changing any of the default settings on the modem.

On Ubuntu 22.04, I tried running pppoeconf. After executing it, **plog** displayed the following output:

```
    plog
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: local  LL address fe80::80c3:5152:b2ce:92b6
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: remote LL address fe80::f263:f9ff:fe16:d620
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: replacing old default route to eno1 [192.168.1.91]
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: local  IP address 20.0.1.172
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: remote IP address 20.0.0.1
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: primary   DNS address 45.116.2.238
    Jul 26 22:13:27 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[103311]: secondary DNS address 8.8.8.8
```

**sudo ip -d addr ls** displayed the following:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:1e:67:d7:f6:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        altname enp3s0
        inet 192.168.1.68/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fed7:f60c/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:1e:67:d7:f6:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fed7:f60d/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    29: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
        link/ppp 
        inet 20.0.1.172 peer 20.0.0.1/32 scope global ppp0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::80c3:5152:b2ce:92b6 peer fe80::f263:f9ff:fe16:d620/128 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**/etc/network/interfaces** file was modified by pppoeconf as:

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

    iface dsl-provider inet ppp
    pre-up /bin/ip link set eno1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
    provider dsl-provider

    auto eno1
    iface eno1 inet manual
```

I use /etc/systemd/network folder to configure my network. The 20-static.network file I created in it is:

```
       [Match]
       MACAddress=00:1e:67:d7:f6:0c

       [Network]
       Address=192.168.1.68/24
       DNS=8.8.8.8
       DNS=8.8.4.4
```

I am unable to ping to 8.8.8.8 or any other external IP. If I replace the Gateway address entry to another IP address where the ISP has given me some static IP addresses, then I can ping to any address. And yes, the IP address of the modem is set (by default) to 192.168.1.1.

Its been frustrating to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT BASED UPON ANSWER AND COMMENTS:**

Based upon the comments, I deleted the Gateway entry for en01.

The route command now displays:

```
 Destination  Gateway  Genmask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
 default      0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0         U     0      0     0 ppp0
 20.0.0.1     0.0.0.0  255.255.255.255 UH    0      0     0 ppp0
 192.168.1.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0   U     0      0     0 eno1
```

I tried to ping and check tcpdump by first setting eno1 to be connected thru a switch to a router which routes properly.

```
  ping 8.8.8.8 -i 5 -c 2
  sudo tcpdump -ni eno1 #In another window
  12:18:16.008892 IP 192.168.1.68 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 6, seq 1, length 64
  12:18:16.024989 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.1.68: ICMP echo reply, id 6, seq 1, length 64
  12:18:21.014143 IP 192.168.1.68 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 6, seq 2, length 64
  12:18:21.030392 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.1.68: ICMP echo reply, id 6, seq 2, length 64
```

Then I switched back the cable from eno1 to the modem and here is the output of tcpdump when I ping to 8.8.8.8

```
  ping 8.8.8.8 -i 5 -c 2
  sudo tcpdump -ni ppp0 #In another window
  12:30:51.504465 IP 20.0.2.75 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9, seq 1, length 64
  12:30:56.757509 IP 20.0.2.75 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9, seq 2, length 64
```

I am not getting the ICMP reply.

The modem connection appears to be OK based upon this:

```
   tail -200 /var/log/syslog|grep pppd
   Jul 27 12:28:03 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eno1
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: Remote message: Authentication success,Welcome!
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: PAP authentication succeeded
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: peer from calling number F0:63:F9:16:D6:20 authorized
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: local  LL address fe80::1c37:674c:4463:8995
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: remote LL address fe80::f263:f9ff:fe16:d620
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: local  IP address 20.0.2.75
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: remote IP address 20.0.0.1
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: primary   DNS address 45.116.2.238
   Jul 27 12:28:06 ram-S1200RP-SE pppd[5452]: secondary DNS address 8.8.8.8
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PPPoE in use, the modem is *not* your gateway and you shouldn't configure it as one. The modem, even if it's a router, doesn't have any Internet connection for itself so it can't do anything with your packets.

In other words, the only default route that you should have is the one through the ppp0 tunnel interface – not directly through Ethernet.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give the specific "ip" or "route" commands or config entries in files to do that in my above case?

Comment: You need to *remove* the eno1 config entries that you currently have.

Comment: please see my update to the question. I understand the tunnelling aspect of ppp now.The default route is set to  ppp0. Please provide what other issues I need to check or understand.  I think I am just a step away from getting this to work.

Comment: If you use `tcpdump -ni ppp0`, does it show your ping packets (or other packets) going out, do they have the correct IP addresses?

Comment: I have added a few logs at the end of the question including from tcpdump -ni ppp0

Comment: Finally got it resolved. The ISP had some issues with respect to MAC authentication (or so they said). They had to reset it. It appears that everytime I move to a new system, they will have to reset the MAC. It is a local ISP I am trying. I have a national ISP with my other servers where I do not have such issues.  I have a few static IPs there.  Thanks for all the help.